Differences in Yajnopavita and Sandhyavandanam by region, Sakha, Veda and Brahmin group?
Are there any differences in how the Yajnopavita is worn among groups of Brahmins? among various Pancha Dravida and Pancha Gauda groups? or is it the same three-stringed white thread for all?
What are the differences apparent in conducting Sandhyavandanam by Veda, Sakha, Sutra, Brahmanas and Dravida-Gauda classification?
How do Krsna Yajurvedin Namboodiris do Sandhyavandanam?
